# Delete entire row, not clear APACHE POI

Tags: apache-poi, java-7, delete-row

I want to delete a specific ROW not clear. In my case it will always be the first row(0). I've already search and I found the code below. I've implemented but it continues to only clear the row.

```
private void removeRow(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    Writer.write("LAST ROW NUM: " + lastRowNum);
    if(rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum){
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if(rowIndex == lastRowNum){
        XSSFRow removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if(removingRow != null){
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

If I the query doesn't return data I have to delete the first row of the sheet (that contains the headers).

Comment: Why aren't you doing the same thing in all cases?

Comment: Not sure why you ask that, but the way that the project is implemented the method doesn't need to be public

Comment: I've try this method in a different sheet and it worked. Maybe the problem is that I can't remove  the dropdown arrow :/